# Twitter API: statuses/home_timeline not returning tweets using max_id as iterative marker

Tags: javascript, json, api, twitter

I'm using a javascript based backend (Parse, until it goes down) to hit the Twitter API to store basic metadata of tweets from my own timeline into my cloud database.

My strategy was to grab 100 tweets, store any with links, and use the oldest tweet (regardless of containing a link) as the new iterative max_id each time. This worked at first, allowing me to store 355 recent tweets from my timeline in my backend, and then the Twitter API started only returned a blank array. My code didn't change.

I'm using the string structure below in a valid httpRequest to hit the Twitter API (correct authentication credentials, etc.).

var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?user_id=" + twitterId + "&max_id=" + max_id_segment + "&count=" + requestCount;

The max_id I'm using is a valid value, requestCount = 100. My first thought was the Twitter API has a default limit of how many tweets it will return (800 maybe?) so if I passed that mark (reminder, the 355 tweets I stored are only those tweets with urls in them), then maybe it's cutting me off?

I don't understand why I wouldn't be able to iteratively go back and parse my own timeline for tweets indefinitely while adhering to API restrictions.

Any help is welcome!